# Capture payment Paypal

Tags: paypal

This is the code i used for capture payments in Paypal

```
OAuthTokenCredential tokenCredential = new OAuthTokenCredential("<CLIENT_ID>", "<CLIENT_SECRET>");

var accessToken = tokenCredential.GetAccessToken();
Authorization authorization = Authorization.Get(accessToken, "5RA45624N3531924N");

Capture capture = new Capture();
Amount captureAmount = new Amount();
captureAmount.currency = "USD";
captureAmount.total = "1";
capture.amount = captureAmount;
capture.is_final_capture = true;

Capture responseCapture = authorization.Capture(accessToken, capture);
```

But it says

> Argument type 'string' is not assignable to parameter type 'PayPal.Api.APIContext'

in following line `accessToken` parameter

```
Authorization authorization = Authorization.Get(accessToken, "5RA45624N3531924N");
```

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You specified the token in the first parameter, it's not correct.

According to below definition:

```
public static Authorization Get(APIContext apiContext, string authorizationId)
```

You should specify APIContext type.

Can you try the code like below:

```
var apiContext = Configuration.GetAPIContext();
var authorization = Authorization.Get(apiContext, authorizationId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class 'Configuration.cs'.

```
public static class Configuration
{
    public readonly static string ClientId;
    public readonly static string ClientSecret;

    static Configuration()
    {
        var config = GetConfig();
        ClientId = config["clientId"];
        ClientSecret = config["clientSecret"];
    }

    public static Dictionary<string,string> GetConfig()
    {
        return PayPal.Api.ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();
    }

    private static string GetAccessToken()
    {
        var config = GetConfig();
        OAuthTokenCredential credential = new OAuthTokenCredential(ClientId, ClientSecret, config);
        string accessToken = credential.GetAccessToken();
        return accessToken;
    }

    public static APIContext GetAPIContext()
    {
        string accessToken = GetAccessToken();
        APIContext apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
        apiContext.Config = GetConfig();
        return apiContext;
    }

}
```

GetAPIContext method will return APIContext object. Pass that object as a parameter to Authorization.Get method instead of "accessToken".

```
APIContext apiContext = Configuration.GetAPIContext();
Authorization authorization = Authorization.Get(apiContext, "6SY29185GS4409204");//Provide Payment Id returned after authorizing payment.
```